# Whats the difference between CloudDrive.Delete() and CloudBlobContainer.Delete() in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

CloudDrive is a Blob.

Either way, files are gone. So whats the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a CloudDrive you are actually [deleting the page blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.delete.aspx) **in** a (blob) container. Calling [CloudBlobContainer.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772840) deletes the blob container (together with all the blobs in that container), and calling this method might delete more files than you would want to delete.

Comment: Ohh, I only have 1 file, thats why both looks same. So basically, `CloudDrive.Delete()` works same as `Blob.Delete()`, right?